# Finding a kernel (and its basis) of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm new to the concept of linear tranformations and I would just like somebody to reassure me which source to trust.

According to my Linear Algebra textbook the kernel of the following linear transformation:

$L: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, T(x,y) = (2x-y, 3y-6x)$

is equal to:

$ \operatorname{ker} \ L = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 2x-y=3y-6x=0\} = \{(x,2x) : x \in \mathbb{R} \} = \operatorname{lin}\{(1,2) \} $

whereas according to this website: http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi it's:

$ \operatorname{ker} \ L = \operatorname{lin}\{(0.5,1) \} $

so, which one is the correct answer and why?

Comment: Note $(1,2)=2(0.5,1)$. Is the linear span of $\{(1,2)\}$ the same as the linear span of $\{(0.5,1)\}$?

Comment: I guess it is, so you're saying that both answers are correct? If so, then my teacher should accept either of them on the test?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: OK, thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Note that it is incorrect to say "its basis", because it has more than one basis. (There are very few vector spaces with only one basis.)

Comment: OK, thank you for that tip, fkraiem. :) I was merely quoting my textbook - the question was about "finding the image and the kernel and its bases" and what I wrote in my post was how it was in the textbook.

Answer (score 3):

They are both correct because they are the same answer but given in different, but equivalent ways. Note that $$lin\{(1,2)\}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x=\alpha(1,2),\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\}$$ and we also have $$lin\{(0.5,1)\}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x=\beta(0.5,1),\beta\in\mathbb{R}\}$$ but clearly $\beta(0.5,1)=\frac{1}{2}\beta(1,2)$ and so $lin\{(1,2)\}=lin\{(0.5,1)\}$